# Is it possible to ScaleTransform everything on a Canvas/Grid except for 1 Control?

Tags: wpf

Given the following canvas:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
    </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
    <Button x:Name="scaleButton" Content="Scale Me" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" />
    <Button x:Name="dontScaleButton" Content="DON'T Scale Me" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="50" />
</Canvas>
```

Is it possible to scale 1 button, but not the other when ScaleX and ScaleY changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in XAML. You can do this in code by building the reverse transform and applying it to the object you don't want transformed.

If you want to go fancy, you can build a dependency property that you can attach in XAML to any object you don't want to be transformed by any parent transforms. This dependency property will take the transform of the parent, build a reverse transform and apply it to the object it's attached to.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this was impossible when you asked the question but i would approach it like this:

```
<Button x:Name="dontScaleButton" Content="DON'T Scale Me" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="50"
        LayoutTransform="{Binding LayoutTransform.Inverse,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}}"/>
```

The original transform still seems to have a translative effect on the button though.

Answer (score 3):

You could also restructure the elements so that the elements you don't want to scale with the `Canvas` are not actually children of that `Canvas`.

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <Button x:Name="scaleButton" Content="Scale Me" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" />
    </Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="dontScaleButton" Content="DON'T Scale Me" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="50" />
</Canvas>
```